# Counting ellipses as opposed to periods in a string

Tags: c++

The question may sound simple but I have no idea how to do it.

If in a string I have five points `( . . . . .)`, and I want to count how many punctuation characters are in it, I would want to count 1 ellipses `(...)`, and 2 periods `( . . )`.

How can I do this in c++?

Comment: Well, that sounds like regular expression tokenization to me. It won't happen by just setting some flag or calling a simple C++ function.

Comment: Imagine you have a string like "Bla!Bla?What's this shit... Bro.", and you have to count the puncts ( including ..., . ). How you make the difference between ellipse and regular punct?

Comment: I would use a regular expression-based tokenizer, with non-punctuation characters ignored. I didn't misunderstand your question; I simply pointed out that C++ does not have a simple answer.

Comment: Improved language to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to write a program that finds and counts sequences of dot `'.'` characters, and adjusts the counters for `ellipses` and `periods` upon reaching the end of each sequence.

If you counted `n` consecutive periods, then the count of `ellipses` should be incremented by `n / 3`, and the count of "plain" periods should be incremented by `n % 3`. Above, `/` denotes integer division operation.

For example, if you find a run of seven consecutive dots, `7 / 3` would be `2`, and `7 % 3` would be `1`, so `.......` has two ellipses and one period.